# Why is mdbootstrap simple landing page truncated top and bottom on smart phone

Tags: html

A very simple landing page to test the latest release of bootstrap appears to work correctly on my development machine, responding as expected when the browser window width is changed.

However, on my iPhoneSE (IOS 13.7) the top and bottom of the page is truncated like this:-
[image]

The full page can be seen on a laptop here: https://new-inn-pembridge.co.uk and this is the code:-

```
<div class="container  bg-ltgreen">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height: 100vh;">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1>The New Inn, Pembridge</h1>
      <img class="img-fluid" src="img/newinn.jpg" />
      <h5 class="pt-3" style="color: rgb(114, 7, 7);">A brand new website is under construction here.</h5>
      <p class="pb-5" style="color: rgb(114, 7, 7);">Have another look about the end of September!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked it with every browser?

I just checked it in my POCO F1, chrome browser (Android) and this page is getting displayed as expected. Kindly, check if you are using Safari, chrome or any other so that it gets clear that which browser is giving problem.

Comment: Sorry,I should have made it clear that it worked perfectly with all browsers on the development machine and that the problem was with smartphones.  It was a rushed mod to a simple page and I missed the obvious!  The simple answer is to remove the **style="height: 100vh;"** directive.